# Is there any easy to implement webapp security/authorization/role library out there?

Tags: asp.net

Is there any security/authorization/role for asp.net that is simpler and easier to implement than the default ASP.net membership?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never been a fan of membership, but implementing authorization and role-based security in ASP.NET is easy and works quite well.

[How to implement Authentication (MS KB301240)](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/301240/EN-US/)

[How to implement Role-Based Security (MS KB311495)](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311495)